# Remove arrow on JavaFX menuButton

Tags: javafx, fxml, javafx-css

Hi JavaFX Stylesheet expert,

How do I remove the default arrow on JavaFX menuButton.

I have figured how to change the color and make in unvisible with

```
.menu-button {
    -fx-mark-color: transparent;
}
```

or

```
.menu-button .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

but, I don't want the gap because of the unvisible arrow.

Thanks for your advice.

Best Regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we look into the source code of `MenuButtonSkinBase`, the sub structure of `MenuButton` seems to be

```
MenuButton
   |——— label (LabeledImpl)
   |——— arrowButton (StackPane)
            |——— arrow (StackPane)
```

So to hide the "arrow" it is enough to set padding to 0 for both StackPanes:

```
.menu-button > .arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.menu-button > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works great and can be combinied: .menu-button > .arrow-button, .menu-button > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

Answer (score -3):

## There are several ways to do this, here are four. The code is Jython with JavaFX. You can edit it for your needs.

---

> First, the enum, for context.

```
public enum URLBarArrowConstants {
     //URLBarArrow Constants
     BYCSS_AND_SHAPE,
     BYCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE,
     NOCSS_AND_SHAPE,
     NOCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE;
}
```

> Second, the css files, for context.

EG #1

```
/*ComboBox's Arrow is a Region.*/
.combo-box .arrow-button .arrow {
     -fx-shape: "...";
     -fx-scale-shape: true;
     -fx-position-shape: true;
}
```

EG#2

```
/*ComboBox's Arrow is a Region.*/
.combo-box .arrow-button .arrow {
    /*Setting either of these two will do.*/
     -fx-background-color: transparent; 
     -fx-opacity: 0.0;  
}

/*ComboBox's Arrow Button is a Stack Pane.*/
.combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-image: url("..<file>.png");
}
```

---

> The method, in my main file.

```
def setCustomURLBarArrow(self, url_bar, scene, URLBarArrowConstant):
    from javafx.scene.paint import Paint
    from javafx.scene.shape import Shape, SVGPath, FillRule
```

### Don't configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS, instead, do it programmatically and change the Regions SVG Shape

```
if URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.NOCSS_AND_SHAPE:

    #SVG Object
    previous_url_bar = SVGPath()

    #SVG Path
    previous_url_bar.setContent("...") # edit this 

    #SVG Fill Rule
    previous_url_bar.setFillRule(FillRule.NON_ZERO)

    #Set Fill -- 
    previous_url_bar.setFill(Paint.valueOf(Color.web("...").toString())) //edit here

    #Apply CSS Sheet
    url_bar.applyCss()

    #Set Region's Shape
    arrow_region = url_bar.lookup(".arrow").setShape(previous_url_bar)
```

## Configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS and change the Regions SVG Shape

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.BYCSS_AND_SHAPE:
    #Apply Stylesheet for URL Bar
    scene.getStylesheets().add(File("..<file>.css").toURI().toString()) //edit here
```

## Configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS but instead, merely hide the arrow by setting the transparency/opacity values and set a background.

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.BYCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE:
    #Apply Stylesheet for URL Bar
    scene.getStylesheets().add(File("..<file>.css").toURI().toString()) //edit here
```

## Don't configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS, instead, do it programmatically and merely hide the arrow by setting the transparency/opacity values and set a background.

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.NOCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE:

    from javafx.scene.paint import Paint
    from javafx.scene.layout import CornerRadii
    from javafx.scene.layout import Background, BackgroundSize, BackgroundImage, BackgroundPosition, BackgroundRepeat, BackgroundFill

    #Apply CSS Sheet
    url_bar.applyCss()

    #Grab Arrow(Region), ArrowButton(StackPane) ComboBox properties
    arrow_region = url_bar.lookup(".arrow")
    arrow_button = url_bar.lookup(".arrow-button")

    #Either Set Opacity to 0 or set background color to transparent.
    arrow_region.setOpacity(0.0)
    arrow_region.setBackground( Background( array(BackgroundFill, [BackgroundFill( Paint.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT.toString()), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)]) ) )

    #Set a Background Image for the .arrow-button StackPane.
    arrow_button.setBackground(Background( array(BackgroundImage, [BackgroundImage( Image( String(File('..<file>.png').toURI().toString()), True) , BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)] ) ) )       //if you want, edit this
```