# JavaFX remove arrow from a single menuButton

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to remove the arrow from a single menu button by using CSS:

```
MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
menuButton.getStyleClass().add("menuButtonWOarrow");
```

I found [Remove arrow on JavaFX menuButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210117/remove-arrow-on-javafx-menubutton) but that is taking affect on all menu buttons.

How would be the correct definition for this in CSS please?

```
.menuButtonWOarrow{
...
}
```

Edit - Thanks to James comment, this is working:

```
.menuButtonWOarrow > .arrow-button > .arrow {
 -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use the CSS class you defined, `.menuButtonWOarrow` in place of the `.menu-button` CSS class in the CSS code in the accepted answer. Then it will apply only to the menu buttons you give that class name, not to all menu buttons. Post a [mre] if it's not working the way you want.